# How to get the number of rows in a Pandas chunk?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm reading a huge csv file by iterating over chunks. How can I get the size of the currently processed chunk? Especially the last chunk may have smaller number of rows than defined with the parameter `chunksize`.

```
reader = pd.read_table('myFile.csv', sep=';', chunksize=100)
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `reader.shape[0]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need check length of `DataFrame`:

```
for x in reader:
    print (len(x.index))
    print (len(x))
    print (x.shape[0])
```

Comment: Great! `x.shape[0]` is what I was looking for. Thanks!